# Shaders are not working in android device when the device goes to lock mode and resumed

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, cocos2d-x

First time i am developing android app with cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4 on Samsung GT-N8000, so help me if anyone having idea on this topic .

Everything works fine with shaders on this device but I found error when the device goes to lock mode and unlocked.

Comment: What is the error? How did you determine that the problem is your shaders? What does your app do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya. We had the same problem.  Whatever the custom shaders added to the 'shadercache' doesn't work once app goes to background and resumed from their. Just try to reset the your custom shaders and add a new  shader in its place.

For more info check `CCShaderCache::reloadDefaultShaders()` which is called called app resume.

```
  CCGLProgram * program = CCShaderCache::sharedShaderCache()->programForKey("customshader");
   //reset the old
    if(program)
        program->reset();

{
    CCGLProgram * p = new CCGLProgram();
    .....
    .....
    p->updateUniforms();
    //add new shader
    CCShaderCache::sharedShaderCache()->addProgram(p, "customshader");
    p->release();

}
```